# JupyterLab skips the first 22 lines when reading and writing a file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Strange issue, when I run this code:

```
data = open("data.txt", "r")
output = open("output.txt", "w")

for line in data:
     output.write(line)
```

It will only start to write onto the output file at line 22

data.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

output.txt

```
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

This only happens when running it in a JupyterLab notebook. Bug or feature? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You don't appear to be closing your files (although I would expect that to cause data to be missing from the end, rather than the beginning).

Comment: Just be careful with opening a file in one cell, and doing something with it later in another. Something like that was what caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Huh, strange because I tried almost similar code on my machine and it copies all the 30 inputs. However, the only different thing I did was use the absolute file path so my code was:

```
data = open("C:\Users\User\Jupyter Notebook\data.txt", "r")
outputs = open("C:\Users\User\Jupyter Notebook\outputs.txt", "w")
for line in data:
    outputs.write(line)
```

Can you see if this method works?

Comment: Yeah I made it work, don't remember what I did but had something to do with me having opened the file before in the code.